An Anagram Brainteaser
An Anagram Brainteaser
An anagram (for the uninitiated) is a word made up of the rearranged letters of another word.
There exists a word that is an anagram of itself. In fact, there exist THREE.
Two show up in the OED, along with the root word of the third.

What are they?

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

The three words in question are

 FLIEST (being a superlative, this one does not appear in the OED on its own)
STIFLE
FILETS

These are of course

 anagrams of the word ITSELF!


OK (in the original meaning of Oll Korrect) except: Filets shows up on an internet search of OED. Fliest does not.

interesting. I didn't double check myself but I assumed the plural would be the least likely to get its own listing (especially since "fliest" wouldn't appear next to "fly"). I'll make a quick edit to set that straight

Thems dictionaries love to keep their gates.
